# Make all Quicktabs closed by default

Tags: 7, blocks, nodes

Is there any way to set all of the tabs on Quicktabs to **closed** or **inactive** by default?

I would like, that if I visit the page then the first Quicktab isn't open by default. In this inherited site there are images and content underneath this open tab that I would like visible instead of an opened tab.

Would I have to implement something using JavaScript or is there a better option beside Quicktabs?

---

Quicktabs Version: 7.x-3.8 | Drupal Version: 7.57

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you might need to add some jQuery to your theme.

Here is a way to do it.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#id-of-my-custom-block h3:first").trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: will try this out and report back, thx

Comment: WHERE in the theme are you doing this?